Customizing Slack Notifications for Uptime Kuma
I have set up Uptime Kuma to monitor some of my website URLs. If any URL goes down, it sends a notification to my Slack channel. I have also customized the Slack message format.
How I Customized the Slack Notification Message in Uptime Kuma
1) Setting > Notification
2) Setup Notification > Notification Type > Webhook
3) Friendly name > <MY-NAME-HERE>
4) Post URL:- My Slack channel URL
5) Request body > Custom body

COSTUME BODY
{
  "blocks": [
    {
      "type": "section",
      "text": {
        "type": "mrkdwn",
        "text": "*Project Name:* <PROJECT-NAME-HERE>\n*Date:* 2024-12-06\n*UTC Time:* 2024-12-06T14:35:00Z\n*Status:* {{status}}"
      }
    },
    {
      "type": "divider"
    },
    {
      "type": "context",
      "elements": [
        {
          "type": "mrkdwn",
          "text": "This notification is dynamically generated. Ensure all data is correct."
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}

It is unable to send the UP or DOWN status notifications to Slack.
You can see the image
